What is affecting my BlackBox signal (LTspice)?
How come my black box (BB) signal is affected when connected to my inverse system? Should the black box output not be the same as when there is no inverse system attached? If not why?
The connected black box signal is taken at the connection before the inverse system so it should have the same signal as the original black box right? Why does the LTspice simulation show me otherwise?




The questions two LTspice circuits, one with a BB node and one with BBConnnectIdeal node where the BBConnnectIdeal node has some additional R17, C7 and R18 components connected which will attenuate the output. I'm not sure I understand the question of why BBConnnectIdeal won't be attenuated compared to BB.

In short, your black box has a finite output impedance so it's not "ideal".

In order for your "black box" to not be affected by the attached circuit either the attached circuit would need to have an infinite impedance, or the black box circuit would need to have zero impedance. Otherwise the attached circuit will load down the black box circuit. As it is the impedances are roughly equal so they act like a voltage divider cutting your signal almost in half, that's why you see close to a 6 dB loss.
If you want your black box signal to not be affected you can put a voltage Controlled Voltage Source as a buffer as seen here:

The VCVS acts like an infinite input impedance, zero output impedance, unity gain (if it's value parameter is set to 1) buffer. You can see that the output of the black box with the load is the same as the output of an identical black box without a load.
